# How stop a loop swift 3

Tags: swift, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to create a ticking noise what continues till you hit the minus button. The only problem I have is that I can't click on the minus button because the plus button stays pressed. It probably stays pressed because of the loop it can't get out of. Already thanks for the answers!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var telLabel: UILabel!

    var number = 0
    var timeline = "no"

    @IBAction func plus(_ sender: Any) {
        number += 1
        telLabel.text = "\(number)"
        timeline = "yes"
        tijdlijn()
    }

    func tijdlijn(){
        while timeline == "yes"{
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1103))
            sleep(2)
        }
    }

    /*   if timeline = "yes"{
    repeat{
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1103))
        sleep(3)
    } while timeline == "yes"
     */

    //4095
    @IBAction func min(_ sender: Any) {
        number -= 1
        telLabel.text = "\(number)"
        timeline = "no"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out which loop you are talking about?

Comment: **Never** use `sleep` on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Timer for tasks like this. Try to use this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var telLabel: UILabel!

var number = 0

var timeline = false

var timer: Timer!

@IBAction func plus(_ sender: Any) {

    timeline = !timeline

    if timeline {
        number += 1
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.tijdlijn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } else {
        number -= 1

        timer.invalidate()
    }

    telLabel.text = "\(number)"
}

func tijdlijn(){
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1103))
}
```

And use only one action touchupinside - func plus. Remove minus touchupinside action.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `timeline` a property of your class. And access it by `self.timeline`. This make it can be accessed in the class. When the  `timeline` become unmatched, the loop will stoped.